# Bold math font?

Tags: fonts, math-fonts

How to make the *text* and *math formulas* to **have the same font type as CM** but **bold** like palatino font?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[margin=2.25cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}

    Nowadays, English is an international language, and most young people are learning this language with the hope of being able to communicate with people on over the world.\\[3pt]

    Hiện nay, tiếng Anh là một ngôn ngữ quốc tế, và phần lớn giới trẻ đang theo học thứ tiếng này với hi vọng được tiếp xúc nhiều hơn với bạn bè trên khắp thế giới. 
    $$ \int\limits_{-1}^{1}\dfrac{\mathrm{e}^x}{\mathrm{e}^{2x}+1}+\dfrac{\mathrm{e}^{2x}+1}{\mathrm{e}^x+1}\;\mathrm{d}x $$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: There is `\mathbf` for bold face math and `\textbf` for text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SX!

Hello, I'm from Vietnam too! :)

Chào bạn, mình cũng đến từ Việt Nam đây :)

If you want to make the math formulars **bold**, as Skillmon said, you can use `\mathbf{}` and `\textbf{}`:

Nếu bạn muốn làm công thức toán học in **đậm**, thì như bạn Skillmon đã nói, bạn có thể dùng `\mathbf{}` và `\textbf{}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\[\mathbf{\int\limits_{-1}^{1}\dfrac{\textbf{e}^x} {\textbf{e}^{2x}+1}+\dfrac{\textbf{e}^{2x}+1}{\textbf{e}^x+1}\;\textbf{d}x}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to make Palatino as your math font (in pdfLaTeX), you can use `\usepackage{mathpazo}` (I suggest using `\usepackage{palatino}` also):

Nếu bạn muốn công thức toán của bạn được viết bằng font chữ Palatino trong pdfLaTeX thì bạn có thể dùng `\usepackage{mathpazo}` (mình khuyên nên dùng kèm với `\usepackage{palatino}` -- khi đó cả văn bản sẽ nhận Palatino làm phông chính):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\begin{document}
\[\mathbf{\int\limits_{-1}^{1}\dfrac{\textbf{e}^x}{\textbf{e}^{2x}+1}+\dfrac{\textbf{e}^{2x}+1}{\textbf{e}^x+1}\;\textbf{d}x}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT**

If you want to make the whole document bold, you can use this command in your preamble:

Nếu bạn cần để phông đậm cả văn bản, dùng lệnh sau (cho vào *trước* `\begin{document}`):

```
\renewcommand{\seriesdefault}{\bfdefault}
```

If you want the main font and the math font to be absolutely similar (which is not really necessary), you should use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX. Install the `cmuserif.ttf` or `palatino.ttf` to your `.tex` file, and use

Nếu bạn muốn font toán giống hệt font bình thường, bạn nên chuyển về XeLaTeX hoặc LuaLaTeX; cài font `cmuserif.ttf` hay `palatino.ttf` vào file `.tex` của bạn và dùng lệnh

```
\setmainfont{cmuserif.ttf}
\setmathfont{cmuserif.ttf}
```

(**the `.ttf` files are named by me -- your file name should be different**)

(**tên các file `.ttf` được đặt bởi mình -- tên file trong máy của bạn có thể khác**)

Comment: hehe, giờ mới có 1 người việt nam để t nói chuyện nè! tui cũng đã làm như ông rồi, nhưng ngặt nỗi là mấy cái dấu ư, ơ đó, nó không tròn giống CM font, cái tui cần là làm cho cả văn bản lẫn công thức đều đậm và chữ ư,ơ phải tròn giống CM font. :-))

Comment: Nice answer (+1). It is of course fun to write in Vietnamese for a compatriot (I do it myself sometimes as well for fellow Dutch users), but it is a bit distracting to do it throughout the post - and it invites Vietnamese-only comments as shown here, which makes it hard for other people to participate.

Comment: @Marijn. :)), sorry. use "\mathbf and \textbf" but these answer is not the key to my question.

Comment: @TrongVuong I edited my answer. Hope that it is what you want! // Mình đã sửa câu trả lời một chút. Hy vọng nó là thứ bạn cần.

Comment: Probably a better idea to have a look at the `bm` package and command, to avoid ending up in upright letters.

Comment: there are many suitable fonts for my questions but only one of two condition. :-))

Comment: @daleif I totally agree with you.

Comment: @daleif Well, I haven't used (and will use) the `bm` package usually, so I'm afraid I will post it in a wrong way :) Can you make it as your own answer?

Answer (score 0):

If you can use LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX, New Computer Modern Book is a heavier version of the default font (Computer Modern).  It also supports math.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{newcomputermodern}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[margin=2.25cm]{geometry}

\babelprovide[import]{vietnamese}

\begin{document}
    Nowadays, English is an international language, and most young people are learning this language in the hope of being able to communicate with people all over the world.\\[3pt]

\begin{otherlanguage}{vietnamese}
    Hiện nay, tiếng Anh là một ngôn ngữ quốc tế, và phần lớn giới trẻ đang theo học thứ tiếng này với hi vọng được tiếp xúc nhiều hơn với bạn bè trên khắp thế giới.
\end{otherlanguage}
    \[ \int\limits_{-1}^{1}\dfrac{\mathrm{e}^x}{\mathrm{e}^{2x}+1}+\dfrac{\mathrm{e}^{2x}+1}{\mathrm{e}^x+1}\;\mathrm{d}x \]

\end{document}
```

[image: New Computer Modern Book sample]

If you’re asking how to make the weight of your math font match your bold text font, use the `\boldmath` command before entering math mode.

In this case, the bold math-mode fonts are not set up by default, so it takes an extra line or two to define them.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{newcomputermodern}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[margin=2.25cm]{geometry}

\setmathfont[version=bold, FakeBold=1.15]{NewCMMath-Book}
\setboldmathrm{NewCM10-Bold}
\newcommand\upe{\symup{e}}

\babelprovide[import]{vietnamese}

\begin{document}
    Nowadays, English is an international language, and most young people are learning this language in the hope of being able to communicate with people all over the world.

\begin{otherlanguage}{vietnamese}
    \bfseries
    Hiện nay, tiếng Anh là một ngôn ngữ quốc tế, và phần lớn giới trẻ đang theo học thứ tiếng này với hi vọng được tiếp xúc nhiều hơn với bạn bè trên khắp thế giới.
\end{otherlanguage}
   \boldmath  \[ \int\limits_{-1}^{1}\dfrac{\upe^x}{\upe^{2x}+1}+\dfrac{\upe^{2x}+1}{\upe^x+1} \mathop{}\mathrm{d}x \]

\end{document}
```

[image: New Computer Modern Bold sample]

If you want to insert blank lines between each paragraph, you might want `\usepackage{parskip}`.  And English prepositions are tough.  They don’t really make any logical sense.  On behalf of my ancestors, I apologize.